# Screen Navigation Header wont display in stacked Drawer Navigation ....React Navigation V2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

So for some reason I can not seem to get any header titles to appear for screens nested within my Drawer Navigator. I have researched this topic pretty heavily and still haven't found a solution.

Some sites have said that the navigationOptions need to be called as a function => Tried and didnt work.

Some have said that because my Drawer Navigator is nested within a Stack Nav that my individual screens for the Drawer should be their own individual Stacks....
but when I did that it only created what seemed to be a small  beneath the nav bar with the header inside, floated to the left.

Ive tried declaring the navigationOptions in the Navigators and statically via each screen but nothing seems to work and I have no clue why this is being so difficult.

Ive used the old React Navigation V1 and this was never a problem. If anyone has any solutions or suggestions, that would be greatly appreciated.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator, createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import {View,Text,StyleSheet,Platform,TouchableOpacity,Image,StatusBar} from 'react-native';

import LoginScreen from '../screens/LoginScreen';
import HomeScreen from '../screens/HomeScreen';
import ProfileScreen from '../screens/ProfileScreen';
import CharityScreen from '../screens/CharityScreen';
import RunScreen from '../screens/RunScreen';


const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen
  },
  Profile: {
    screen: ProfileScreen
  },
  Charity: {
    screen: CharityScreen
  },
  Run: {
    screen: RunScreen
  },
});

const StackNav = createStackNavigator(
  { Login: LoginScreen,
    DrawerNav: DrawerNavigator
  },
  {
   navigationOptions: {
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: '#2b3991',
    },
    headerTintColor: '#fff',
    },
  },
);

export default StackNav;
```

And here is my individual screen with the navigationOptions declared there:

```
import React, { Component} from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { Container, Content, Card, CardItem, Header, Left, Body, Button, Icon, Title, H1 } from 'native-base';


class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    headerMode: 'screen',
    title: 'Home',
    headerTitle: 'Home'
  };
  render() {
    return (
       <View style={{ flex: 1 , flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
            <Card>
              <CardItem header style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center'}} >
                <H1 style={{ justifyContent: 'center'}} >Charity</H1>
              </CardItem>
              <CardItem>
                <Body>
                  <Icon name="images" style={{ fontSize: 50, borderWidth: 5 , borderStyle: 'dashed', borderRadius: 10, padding: 20}} />
                </Body>
              </CardItem>
            </Card>
            <Card style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'white', borderWidth: 2 }}></Card>
            <Card style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'white', borderWidth: 2 }}></Card>
        </View>
    );
  }
}

export default HomeScreen;
```

Here is an image of my app when I created individual Stack Navs for each screen in my nested Drawer Nav. The code I have posted above does not produce this image.....but just wanted to add it to show what happened when I tried this....because this confuses me as well.
[Image of Rendered App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKWMG.png)

Comment: what you mean "does not produce this image"?

Comment: That image is produced when I made every screen inside my drawer nav a stack navigator. The above code produces a typical nav header but with no title

Comment: ref https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1632#issuecomment-305291994

Answer (score 6):

Navigation options can only be configured its direct parent in version 2.

- Create individual stack for your each screen.
- And then you can configure the **navigation options of createStackNavigator** at respective screen.

I have created the [expo link](https://snack.expo.io/HkEKAXJ7m) for you.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. I had setup my stack like this because of the Login Screen. But I just found out about the Swtich Navigator and implemented that instead and it all works like a charm now. But what exactly do you mean navigation options can only be configured in its direct parent? Can you please give an example?